# Why does this conditional work?

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

How does this conditional work:

```
    function play(){
    if (typeof gameInterval != "undefined")
        clearInterval(gameInterval);
        gameInterval = setInterval(gameLoop, 100);
        allowPressKeys = true;
}
```

The variable gameInterval is only defined inside this function, there is no global variable. 
 So when play() is called gameInterval IS undefined.  Since this conditional does something when gameInterval is NOT undefined, I don't understand why it works.  Can someone explain?  I'm trying to understand this so I can manipulate it later in my code.

Comment: If not global, but declared somewhere in an outer scope. As you can see, `gameInterval` is not declared in `play` function, hence it is not local to `play`. Might be an implicit global, though.

Comment: If `gameInterval` was only within the function scope it would have `let`/`var` somewhere declaring it.

Comment: You have not declared the variable anywhere, so it is automatically defined on the global scope.

Comment: As the curly braces are missing, only the first line after the conditional is part of it, clearing the interval if it exists, so the next line defining `gameInterval` always runs, declaring the variable in the global scope, so it's set the next time the function runs

Comment: *"The variable gameInterval is only defined inside this function"* I don't see it defined anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are missing the curly braces around your if block only the first statement after the if is conditionally executed. Your indentation confuses this issue. You are really doing this:

```
function play() {
    if (typeof gameInterval != "undefined") 
        clearInterval(gameInterval);
    gameInterval = setInterval(gameLoop, 100);
    allowPressKeys = true;
}
```

the statement:

```
gameInterval = setInterval(gameLoop, 100);
```

is always executed;

Where as you probably mean this:

```
function play() {
    if (typeof gameInterval != "undefined") {
        clearInterval(gameInterval);
        gameInterval = setInterval(gameLoop, 100);
        allowPressKeys = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that happens when the condition is satisfied is:

```
clearInterval(gameInterval);
```

The next two lines:

```
gameInterval = setInterval(gameLoop, 100);
allowPressKeys = true;
```

are always executed.

Formatting the code like this makes it easier to understand:

```
function play(){
    if (typeof gameInterval != "undefined") {
        clearInterval(gameInterval);
    }
    gameInterval = setInterval(gameLoop, 100);
    allowPressKeys = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to compare this against the undefined value? `gameInterval !== undefined` (no quotes)  might be what you are looking for.

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_undefined.asp

Comment: `typeof` always returns a string. A string is never equal to `undefined`. *"The result of the typeof function will never give you a string that equals "undefined""* That is wrong. Try `typeof undefined`.

Comment: ah.  makes sense.  Thank you both!

Comment: Can you explain why it would make a difference to use `gameInterval !== undefined` instead of `typeof gameInterval != "undefined"` ? Besides the OP says that their code "works" and wants to know why. Why are you proposing to change something?

Comment: that is not the case try running the code snippet in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the variable anywhere hence it gets declared in the global scope hence typeof != "undefined"

```
gameInterval = setInterval(gameLoop, 100);
```

is always called since it is out of the if scope, this is the way it would've worked normally

```js
if(typeof a =="undefined"){
  var a=5;
  console.log('OK');
}
```

also try running this

```js
function A(){
 a = 5;
}
A();

console.log(typeof a);
```